# How to write a function to fire quickCheck prop_xxx?

Tags: haskell, quickcheck

I am using QuickCheck v1. Here is a simple prop_xxx defined as below:

```
prop_foo :: (Num a) =>[a] -> Bool
prop_foo xs = (reverse.reverse) xs == id xs
```

This can be tested in GHCi correctly:
    quickCheck prop_foo

However, when I tried to wrap the call in a function like:

```
f :: IO ()
f = quickCheck prop_foo
```

It reported the error:

```
Ambiguous type variable `a' in the constraints:
  `Num a' arising from a use of `prop_foo' at Foo.hs:147:15-22
  `Arbitrary a'
    arising from a use of `quickCheck' at Foo.hs:147:4-22
Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
```

Shall I provide something like

```
instance Arbitrary Xxx where
    arbitrary     = ...
    coarbitrary c = ...
```

Thanks a lot.

--
Larry

Answer (score 6):

You have to give it a *monomorphic type signature*, like

```
prop_foo :: [Int] -> Bool
```

After all, the question is: in your original version, which type `a` should `quickCheck` choose to test the function with? `a = Int`? `a = Double`? Something else? The error message complains that `a` is ambiguous, i.e. there is no unique choice for it.

Comment: Precisely, it's just that `ghci` defaults to using `Integer`. That is why `ghci` is not complaining, that is of course for convenience. No?